# postgres db in mapserver

Tags: postgresql, mapserver

I am trying to generate a map in mapserver by connecting a postgres database but it is not displaying any maps. My table name is `a19010100001001`.

mapfile is **LAYER.map**

```
MAP
NAME "MP"
SIZE 400 400
STATUS ON
EXTENT 1143759 4417539 1146436 4420390
UNITS METERS 

WEB
TEMPLATE "template.html"
  IMAGEPATH "C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\output"
  IMAGEURL "/OUTPUT/"
END



LAYER
        CONNECTIONTYPE Postgis
        CONNECTION "host=localhost dbname=postgis20 user=postgres password=******* port=5432"
        DATA "the geom FROM a19010100001001"
    NAME "a19010100001001"
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON
    CLASS
      STYLE
        COLOR 255 235 190
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        SYMBOL 0
      END
    END
END
END
```

**startmap.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>Creating a simple image using Mapserver and a Shapefile</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<h2>Creating a simple image using Mapserver and a Shapefile</h2>
<p><hr><p>
This page simply contains a link which sends a set of instructions to the Mapserver application using a mapfile.<br />
The information stored within the mapfile tells the Mapserver application how to draw the map.<p>
<!-- The following link sends the local file structure path of the mapfile to the web location of the mapserver executable file  -->
<A HREF="http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\LAYER.map">
Click on this link</A> to view a map generated using a Shapefile.
<p><hr><p>

</body>
</html>

**template.html**

<!-- MapServer Template -->
<html>
<head><title>Simple Mapserver Template HTML Document</title></head>
<body bgcolor=#AAAAAA>
<h2>The image below was illustrated based on the instructions sent in the mapfile.</h2>
<!-- When using Mapserver with a template, the Mapserver application looks for the [img] tag within the template document to place the map -->
<IMG SRC="[img]" width=400 height=300 border=0>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Try if STATUS DEFAULT helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `the geom` for `the_geom` (note the underscore).

If the column really includes a space then you must reference it with double quotes: `"the geom"`. This later case is not such a good idea, I would advise you to rename the table column to `the_geom`.